# Rails help with pagination and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, pagination

I am using fgraph to retrieve all of a users status from facebook and will_paginate to paginate the page. Here is my code right now

```
@statuses = FGraph.me_feed(:access_token => @access_token, :limit => 9000)
```

With Facebook, you need to specify the amount to return or else it will only return like 20 records. So I set the limit to 9000 just so I could return all of the records, which in my case was 472.

This is bad coding though. Is there anyway to make it so that you can set the limit to all?

Comment: Is your intent to paginate the results?

Comment: yes, but if you do FGraph.me_feed(:access_token => @access_token, :limit => 9000).paginate(:page => params[:page]), it paginates the page, but it still makes the page have the loading time of loading 9000 results. if you take away the limit, i am only able to retrieve like 20 facebook statuses. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like fgraph supports an :offset param, so you could set up pagination manually (ie not through will_paginate)

perhaps like

```
offset = params[:page].to_i * 20
FGraph.me_feed(:access_token => @access_token, :offset => offset)
```

then manage your previous / next links inside the view.  Doing a numbered page pagination would still be difficult if not impossible without knowing the size of the data set before which unfortunately isn't included in the facebook response I believe.

Atleast with previous / next you would not have to worry about large responses from facebook